# Updating Webapp from ExtJS 3 & DWR to ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, dwr, extjs5

We have a web application which is using ExtJS 3.4 (I know, it's old) and now we are going to migrate it to ExtJS 5.0.
But in the application we are using DWR Framework and in the ExtJS 5 it's not valid the old one.
We are using it in the way of:

```
myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
     id: 'settingStore',
     proxy: new Ext.ux.data.DwrProxy({
     apiActionToHandlerMap: {
           read: {
              dwrFunction: DAO.getSettingsList,
              getDwrArgsFunction: function(request) {
                 return [];
              },
              getDwrArgsScope: this
           }
     }
 }),
```

So at this moment, this is not valid for ExtJS 5. Is DwrProxy for ExtJS 4 valid for ExtJS 5 http://kalmatrongeorgia.ge/dwrExtjs4Store/DwrProxy.js ? Or do we need another implementation?

I am trying to use it as:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
        autoDestroy: true,
        model: 'Setting',
        proxy: new Ext.ux.DwrProxy({
            read: {
                dwrFunction: DAO.getSettingList,
                getDwrArgsFunction: function(request) {return [];}, 
                getDwrArgsScope: this
            },
            write: {
                dwrFunction: DAO.applySettingList,
                getDwrArgsFunction: function(request) {return [];},
                getDwrArgsScope: this
            }

        }),
```

But I am getting the error:

TypeError: this.addEvents is not a function
this.addEvents('exception');

What I have to do?? ( I am a little bit loose and stuck in it)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DWR proxy has not been updated by its authors to the current Ext version. Googling, I have only found [Ext 4 version](https://code.google.com/p/extjs4dwr/) and that also seems abandoned.

You would need to update it yourself or contact the original author to update the proxy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I think it will be a bloody task.

Comment: You can always hire someone to do it for you... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update it yourself. I guess that it should be easy to do, as long as all changes are well documented in Sencha Docs. The one error you mentioned is clearly documented:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addEvents

While updating that proxy, you can learn so much about ExtJS, that you will feel reborn when you're done.